# Почему отображается код HTML, если подключается php require?

Tags: php, html

Проблема странная, вроде ошибок в коде нет. Когда в начало когда вставляешь

```
<?php
require_once ('connection.php');?>
```

показывает в браузере сам HTML код. Сам файл с кодом HTML имеет расширение php.

```
<?php
require_once ('connection.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" Content-Type: "text/html">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
```

Файл connection.php:

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="project";

    $conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    ?>
```

Comment: а что должно отображаться?

Comment: Покажите содержимое файла `connection.php`

Comment: в html ниже код для создания формы регистрации

Comment: Возможно ошибка в подключении и отображение ошибок отключено, по-этому Вы не видите ошибки и в эту же очередь файл не подключается.  Попробуйте заменить на `include_once`